# I am getting an error in SQL for this query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DATE 
FROM TABLE1
MINUS
SELECT TO_CHAR (CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM') RUN_DATE;
```

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to parse query text: Incorrect syntax near "FROM", found "SELECT".... [parser-2904201]

I am trying to get 0 records as doing minus date from the table having format YYYYMM with current date.

Comment: TOAD and `TO_CHAR` don't sound like this is really for (Microsoft) SQL Server ..... check your tags and make sure you tag the RDBMS you're **really** using ....

Comment: `TO_CHAR()` and `MINUS` seems very Oracle-like. Did you mean to tag `sql-server` (Microsoft SQL Server)?

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected result. I don't believe using `MINUS` is correct in this case. Seems you should rather use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The syntax you have is for Oracle,  but the I don't recognize the error message as Oracle's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE` is a reserved word used to specify a `DATE` literal; it cannot be used as an unquoted identifier. Either: use a quoted identifier (with the correct case everywhere it is going to be used); or change the name of the column.

Unless you are using Oracle 23, or later, then a `SELECT` statement must have a `FROM` clause; if you are expecting a single value then use `FROM DUAL`.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT "DATE" 
FROM   TABLE1
MINUS
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM') AS RUN_DATE
FROM   DUAL;
```

However, you can simplify the query to:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       "DATE" 
FROM   TABLE1
WHERE  "DATE" != TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aGKX6sTc)